# How can I retrieve an image from Firebase Storage as data so I can synchronize with texts?

Tags: android, firebase-storage

Is it possible to retrieve an image from Firebase Storage and save it as a variable so it can be used later to display with others fields?

Like, I have saved on database the image download url and if I use the `Picasso.get().load('image_url').into('image_place');` that will load directly the image into the image_place and I can still call a Callback to say when it succeeds but this will load first the image then the others fields, which is not a good ui experience. So, I would like to know if it is possible to retrieve the image download url and save it as another variable to display it later with others variables too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/download-files#download_data_via_url) describes how to get a download URL for a file in Cloud Storage.

> If you already have download infrastructure based around URLs, or just
>   want a URL to share, you can get the download URL for a file by
>   calling the getDownloadUrl() method on a storage reference.
>
> ```
> storageRef.child("users/me/profile.png").getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
>     @Override
>     public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
>         // Got the download URL for 'users/me/profile.png'
>     }
> }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
>     @Override
>     public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
>         // Handle any errors
>     }
> });
> ```

Comment: That won't help. This function requires a login which is not something it is in need right now

Comment: It doesn't require a login if your security rules allow it.  If this is not the case, then consider going back and editing your question to say in more detail what you're trying to accomplish, and the constraints you're working with.